# SELECT inside SELCT in active record codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I want to calculate the time difference 
I've tried query and query work on mysql

```
SELECT  *, CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1,  CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2, (SELECT TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour) from TABLE1
```

and I write in the active record by using codeigniter query builder:

```
$this->db->select('*, CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1,  CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2, (SELECT TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour)');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2','table1.code_number = table2.code_number');    
$query = $this->db->get();
```

the result i can't get value diffhour :(

what's wrong with my code active record?

Comment: you should use table name with all you columns name and remove select in side select ,should be like this `TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour`

Comment: I've tried code like this

$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->select('CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1,  CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2') 
$this->db->select('(SELECT TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour)');

and like this
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->select('CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1,  CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2') 
$this->db->select('TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour');

the result still same i cant get value diffhour

there is another solution?

Comment: what error u get ? something like this unknown column name rhour1 and rhour2 or  some other error

Comment: if i use code 
$this->db->select('(SELECT TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour)');
the result Undefined diffhour

if i use code 
$this->db->select('TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour');
the result unknown column rhour2

but ive tried on mysql its work
SELECT  *, CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1,  CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2, (SELECT TIMEDIFF(rhour2,rhour1) AS diffhour) from TABLE1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Note : make sure you have added table name with all column name just like this `table1.code_number`*

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1) AS rhour1');
$this->db->select('CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2) AS rhour2');
$this->db->select('TIMEDIFF(CONCAT_WS(" ", date2, hour2),CONCAT_WS(" ", date1, hour1)) AS diffhour');

$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2','table1.code_number = table2.code_number');    
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: pls check my answer and let me know what u get?